# Unset actions for terms parent only

Tags: terms

I'm trying to unseting actions for Parent terms only but unsetting the action "view" doesn't work. Terms is always clickable.

Here is what i'm trying to do :

Edit '**Code got malfunctions don't use it**'

```php
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( in_array( 'editor', (array) $user->roles ) ) {

    add_filter( 'tag_row_actions', 'remove_row_actions_term_parent', 10, 2 );
    function remove_row_actions_term_parent( $actions, $term ) {
        if ($term->parent == 0) {
            unset( $actions['delete'] );
            unset( $actions['trash'] );
            unset( $actions['edit'] );
            unset( $actions['view'] );
            unset( $actions['inline hide-if-no-js'] );
        }
        return $actions;
    }

    add_action( 'pre_delete_term', 'restrict_taxonomy_parent_deletion', 10, 2 );
    function restrict_taxonomy_parent_deletion( $term, $taxonomy ) {
        if ($term->parent == 0) {
            wp_die( 'Cette catégorie est protégée.' );
        }
    }

    add_action('edit_terms', 'restrict_taxonomy_parent_edit', 10, 2);
    function restrict_taxonomy_parent_edit( $term, $taxonomy ) {
        if ($term->parent == 0) {
            wp_die('Cette catégorie ne peut être modifiée');
        }
    }

    add_action( 'admin_head', function () {
        $current_screen = get_current_screen();

        // Hides the "Delete" link on all term edit page.
        if ( 'term' === $current_screen->base &&
        'category' === $current_screen->taxonomy ) :
        ?>
            <style>#delete-link { display: none !important; }</style>
        <?php
        endif;
    } );

    // Jquery Unset "-1" on <select></select> for add taxonomies. This will unset the possibility to add parent tax.

    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_script' );
    function load_custom_script() {
        wp_enqueue_script('custom_js_script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/admin-script.js', array('jquery'));
    }
}
```

```
// Jquery Unset "Aucun" on <select></select> for add taxonomies. This will unset the possibility to add parent tax.
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // Unset on cat page
    jQuery("#parent option[value='-1']").remove();
    // Unset on post-new page
    jQuery("#newcategory_parent option[value='-1']").remove();

});
```

I'm not sure if i'm doing the wright way, maybe is there another solution easier ?

Comment: I copy and pasted this code and it worked as expected. The `View` link was removed. Maybe the problem lies elsewhere? Higher priorities maybe?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I think I expressed myself badly, the view link was removed but the term is always clickable. changing priority don't change anything.

Comment: so you're trying to prevent the parent term from being editable? I'm not sure you can do that. Would a redirect work?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Yes, editable and deletable. Actually maybe i can try that with a redirect.